# How to bind rating control for each list item in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

The thing is that i have one list with itemTpl and binding that to one store its displaying some 10 records and working fine code is below

```
 xtype:'list',
  id:'userReviewList',
  title:'User Review',
  cls:'reviewStyle',
  store:'UserReviewStore',
  height:500,
  itemTpl:'<div class="comment">{Comment}</div>' + '<div >{Rating}</div>' + '<div style="display: none" >{ReviewId}</div>'
```

//with the above code am using another rating control in my app, from this below link .
  [http://podlipensky.com/post/2012/03/20/Sencha-Touch-2-ExtuxtouchRating.aspx][1]

//using above list and below panel inside another **panel** as items using layout **'hbox'**

```
 xtype:'panel',
  id:'ratingPanel',
  lex:1,
  layout: {
  animation: {
  duration: 250,
  easing: 'ease-in-out'
             }
          },
  scroll : 'vertical',
   items:[
        {
   xtype: 'rating',
   label : 'Star',
   itemsCount : 5,
   itemCls : 'x-rating-star',
   itemHoverCls : 'x-rating-star-hover'
         }
    ]
```

//Below code is to bind local storage data to list

```
 var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
   var jsonObj = Ext.decode(retrievedObject);
   if (jsonObj != null) {
   if (jsonObj.UserRatings.length != null)
     {
       this.getUserReviewList().getStore().setData(jsonObj.UserRatings);
     }
   }
```

//**Now list coming left side with 10 records and right side panel with only one rating control.So now my main question is how i should bind this rating control inside the list
which appears on all 10 records please help me out**

Comment: Any one please suggest how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you use List & ListItem structure, you can easily add components to your list item. With using itemTpl, you write html and style one row with html. If you use [ListItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.component.ListItem), you can shape your list row with components not html, then you can add rating component to each row.

Hope this helps.